# what to do when i get following dll error while installing composer in xampp

Tags: php, composer-php

I am getting the following error while installing composer 2.0 in the command-line PHP step. I am using xampp as a server.

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or a dll does not exist.

Program Output:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_smtp.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I have checked there is no `php_smtp.dll` in *ext* folder in *xampp* should i add one??

Answer (score 0):

Although last time I checked, *composer* worked on *xamp* just fine without any additional need, but maybe your project's `composer.json` file or some dependency requires that, so you may follow the instructions below.

**php_smtp** extension is inbuilt in latest PHP (5.3 and above) for older versions:

1. Download [php_smtp.dll](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/php_smtp_dll.html) file, *and please scan the downloaded `php_smtp.dll` file with your preferred antivirus-tool and use it at your own risk.*
2. Move the downloaded `php_smtp.dll` file to your "C:\xamp\php\ext" directory.
3. Open `C:\xamp\php\php.ini` file, and go to "Dynamic Extensions" commented section, there copy-paste this line somewhere, maybe below other extensions: `extension=php_smtp.dll`
4. Last but not least, restart `XAMP`.